# How can I upgrade the Ruby version on Passenger?

Tags: apache-http-server, ruby, ruby-on-rails, passenger

How can I uprgade the Ruby version installed on my passenger module for Apache?

I on Debian 7 and it's running Ruby 1.9.1 but I want 2.2.0

Comment: I'm using debian 7, sorry for missing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to install a newer Ruby version. You can do that using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) with [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build#readme) or [RVM](https://rvm.io/). I've found the former to be a little more simple to use and less intrusive. Simply install rbenv and ruby-build according to the documentation, then:

```
rbenv install 2.2.0
```

Once you've installed it, set your global Ruby to 2.2.0 (or whatever the name of the Ruby is you installed):

```
rbenv global 2.2.0
```

You need to reload your shell for this to take effect. Note that `which ruby` will only give you the path to a so-called shim, not the actual Ruby interpreter. To find out the path, simply modify the line below, changing `2.2.0` to whatever version you installed.

Now, in the Passenger configuration, change [the `PassengerRuby`  option](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby) for your virtual host, e.g.

```
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/ruby
```

Reload the server, and you should be done.

Comment: is it the same unter debian 7?

Comment: when I installed passenger for apache2 the ruby installations comes automatically with the installation. isn't there an esier way to do the ruby update?

Comment: @Felix The Ruby versions that come with distributions are often not the latest ones, so you're unlikely to find an official 2.2.0 that you can use directly with `apt-get` (but [there are some PPAs](https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2015/01/05/ruby-2-2-0-packages-for-ubuntu/)). The generally recommended way to get a recent Ruby is to use rbenv or RVM, these days. Compiling from source yourself is also possible, but requires a little more knowledge about Linux in general, and a bit more effort when trying to switch between multiple versions.

Comment: @JakeGould I've been programming Rails since several years. I've read best practices and lots of tutorials, and I've rarely seen people recommend source code based installs without Ruby version managers. I understand that it's a straightforward approach, but it can be overwhelming. At least to me it was like that.